# Scope in event-handling between a controller and a service

Tags: angularjs, event-handling, angularjs-scope

My Controller declares a variable in its scope. I'd like this variable to be accessible inside $rootScope.$on but it does not seem to be the case. That's my issue.

---

**This is my Controller**:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, OnTest) {
    $scope.variable = null;

    $rootScope.$on('eventCalled', function() {
        if ($scope.variable == null) {
            alert("THIS IS MY ISSUE: SHOULD NOT BE NULL");
        }
    });

    $scope.methodCalledFromTheView = function () {
        $scope.variable = {age: 23};
        TestApp.method1();
    }
});
```

---

**This is my service:**

```
app.service('TestApp', function ($rootScope) {
    this.method1 = function () {
        $rootScope.$emit("eventCalled");
    }
});
```

**Output**:

"THIS IS MY ISSUE: SHOULD NOT BE NULL"

What should I change so as to insure $scope.variable is reachable inside $rootScope.$on ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for more of a event based update to the two-way binding.  Also, with the way that `$emit` works, it only sends the event to the $rootScope and not all of it's children. A $broadcast is more suitable to be applied to a controller or directive (anything nested in the DOM), whereas $emit is better for services since services typically **do not create an isolate scope.**

```
// CONTROLLERS SHOULD NOT ACCESS $ROOTSCOPE, BUT USE THEIR OWN $SCOPE
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, TestApp) {
    $scope.variable = null;

    TestApp.broadcastEventCalled();

    TestApp.onEventCalled($scope, function() {
      $scope.variable = {age: 23};
      if ($scope.variable == null) {
          alert("THIS IS MY ISSUE: SHOULD NOT BE NULL");
      }
    });
});
//SERVICE SHOULD ONLY HAVE EVENT THROWERS AND $ROOTSCOPE
app.service('TestApp', function ($rootScope) {
    this.broadcastEventCalled = function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("eventCalled");
    };

    this.onEventCalled = function (scope, callback) {
      return scope.$on('eventCalled', function () {
        callback();
      });
    };
});
```

Hope it helps!